# make <hr> tag invisible in IE6?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

Is there a way to get rid of the border on `<hr>` element in IE6 without a wrapping it in another element? Another requirement is no hacks, unfortunately.

I've managed to do it for all browsers by styling the border as such:

```
hr.clear {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 0px;
}
```

Yet IE6 still renders a 1-pixel white line.

Comment: Why not `border:none`? I think it even works on IE6.

Comment: Both solutions above leave a 1-px line in ALL IE browsers. I'm testing with IETester and IE8 on Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`display: none` does not work because you're completely removing the `<hr>` from element flow. That causes it to stop clearing your floats.

If you're OK with completely hiding it, just use `visibility: hidden` instead. It will still clear floats, and this works on all IEs:

```
hr {
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: clear: both is was a MUST for me, visibility: hidden only didn't work..

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

http://blog.neatlysliced.com/2008/03/hr-image-replacement/

Comment: Yes, I saw this. But I don't need an image, I just need it to be invisible altogether.

Comment: .. `display: none;` would just hide it and the 1px of vertical space that the poster wants will be gone.

Comment: I don't need to hide it but to merely get rid of its border. I need it as a clearing element. Hence, `display: none` is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that IE does not consider `<hr>` borders as "borders". If you set

```
border: 1px #f0f solid;
```

... it'll add a fuchsia border around the existing bevelled border. Fortunately, Firefox and IE8 render this the same and realize that `border: 0;` means I don't want a border. Unfortunately, IE 7 and lower versions don't do this.

So to answer your question... **no**... there isn't a way to get rid of the border on `<hr>` element in **IE6** without a wrapping it in another element or hacking it (I haven't found a way to do this from my experience).

Your options are either wrap the `<hr>` in a `<div>`, if you have a solid background color, set the `color` property to that of the background color, or use images for the background.

Option 1:

```
<div style="height:1px; background: transparent;">
    <hr style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

Option 2:

```
hr.clear {
    border: 0 none;
    height: 1px;
    color: #ffffff; /* if your bg is white, otherwise choose the right color */
}
```

Option 3... check this out: http://blog.neatlysliced.com/2008/03/hr-image-replacement/

Sorry that IE (older versions) doesn't play by the rules. I hope this helps.